# Error on CGAN / InfoGan

Tags: keras, gan, mnist

So i'm trying to execute the code provided here: https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/infogan/infogan.py

Both for InfoGAN and CGAN i get the same error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-489e5ad1b538> in <module>()
      1 infogan = INFOGAN()
----> 2 infogan.train(epochs=50000, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py in to_filehandle(fname, flag, return_opened, encoding)
    390             fh = bz2.BZ2File(fname, flag)
    391         else:
--> 392             fh = open(fname, flag, encoding=encoding)
    393         opened = True
    394     elif hasattr(fname, 'seek'):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'images/0.png'
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

In [Line 207](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/infogan/infogan.py#L207), generated pictures are written to a directory `images`, which must exist. In your case it does not, that's why it throws that error.

Comment: You are absolutly right! Thank you!